# How To Record/Track User Actions in iPhone.....?

Tags: iphone, ios

Is there any easy and effective way to track user activities from my iPhone app. I have to record all actions performed by user in my application without any performance/frozen problems. There should be no limits like per second hits etc.... App is global and cross platform. It is better if I can write my own custom algorithm to make this functional.

Comment: Is Google analytics / event tracking sufficient enough?

Comment: When you say _my iPhone app_, do you mean an iPhone app you wrote/develop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use google analytics

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/

Answer (score 1):

We use a service called Flurry Analytics. It works on all mobile platforms and we have had great experiences with it. Free too!

http://www.flurry.com/flurry-analytics.html

The app can collect all kinds of information in a very versatile manner and is efficient in when it sends the data back the the server. I believe it's only when the app terminates.

On the device side it is super easy to set up and beginning tracking user events.